# Debugging Module Show PHP Errors

Tags: 8, debugging

I saw in a YouTube video someone had made a configuration where if there was a PHP bug in their module, upon cache rebuild it would show the error underneath the "The Website Encountered an Unexpected Error" screen.

I've been running dual screens monitoring the php error log - but would actually prefer to consolidate it into that one screen.  Where is that configuration option found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';`

in file

```
sites/default/settings.php
```

or in `{example}.com/admin/config/development/logging`
you checked in `All messages` after click to `Save configuration`